# Packaging my application for another computer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have developed an application with Python 3.10, the files structure is like

```
- ROOT_FOLDER
   * MyApp_FOLDER
   * MyUtil_FOLDER
```

The application is MyApp , which is using my own functions in MyUtil.

I am trying to deploy this to another computer.
So I tried **zipapp** , but it can only pack the files in MyApp_FOLDER.
Not able to include MyUtil.

Could somebody tell me how to do this correctly ?

p.s **Cannot us PyInstaller since no *.exe is acceptable here**.

Thanks!

Comment: Pyinstaller can create an executable for mac or linux as well.  However I am not certain what you are asking.  What is wrong with just creating a zip archive  of the Root folder and sending it that way?

Comment: Executable files are not acceptable in my environment, sadly.

Comment: Yes it will work if I just archive the whole ROOT folder, but since I got so many other folders for other projects, the whole ROOT archive will be huge... not a good idea.

Comment: Just archive those two folders then?

Comment: @RogerYang Why don't you try zipping and sending those two folders at once? Is that not possible? How are you trying to send those files? Using a pen-drive or some physical connection? Or using a remote connection such as ssh?

Comment: Since zipapp is only able to archive one single folder. Not sure how to archive more than 1 folders...

Comment: @RogerYang can't you send each folder one at a time?